BeanPostprocessorerror - Getting this error while upgrading
2024-11-14T12:18:27,674 INFO \[restartedMain\] \[\] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:208): Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 254 ms. Found 7 JPA repository interfaces.

2024-11-14T12:18:28,961 INFO \[restartedMain\] \[\] o.s.c.c.s.GenericScope - setSerializationId(GenericScope.java:282): BeanFactory id=975db15f-4ce5-3b2e-b807-5b6bc92076a4

2024-11-14T12:18:29,384 WARN \[restartedMain\] \[\] o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - postProcessAfterInitialization(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:437): Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari' of type \[org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari\] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor \[jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor\]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.

2024-11-14T12:18:29,400 WARN \[restartedMain\] \[\] o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - postProcessAfterInitialization(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:437): Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.commons.config.CommonsConfigAutoConfiguration' of type \[org.springframework.cloud.commons.config.CommonsConfigAutoConfiguration\] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor \[jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor\]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.

2024-11-14T12:18:29,405 WARN \[restartedMain\] \[\] o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - postProcessAfterInitialization(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:437): Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerDefaultMappingsProviderAutoConfiguration' of type \[org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerDefaultMappingsProviderAutoConfiguration\] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor \[jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor\]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.

2024-11-14T12:18:29,410 WARN \[restartedMain\] \[\] o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - postProcessAfterInitialization(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:437): Bean 'loadBalancerClientsDefaultsMappingsProvider' of type \[org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerDefaultMappingsProviderAutoConfiguration$$Lambda$812/0x00000008011c56b0\] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor \[jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor\]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.

2024-11-14T12:18:29,418 WARN \[restartedMain\] \[\] o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - postProcessAfterInitialization(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:437): Bean 'defaultsBindHandlerAdvisor' of type \[org.springframework.cloud.commons.config.DefaultsBindHandlerAdvisor\] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor \[jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor\]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.

2024-11-14T12:18:29,425 WARN \[restartedMain\] \[\] o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - postProcessAfterInitialization(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:437): Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration' of type \[org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration\] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor \[jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor\]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.

2024-11-14T12:18:29,434 WARN \[restartedMain\] \[\] o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - postProcessAfterInitialization(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:437): Bean 'stringOrNumberMigrationVersionConverter' of type \[org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$StringOrNumberToMigrationVersionConverter\] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor \[jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor\]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.

2024-11-14T12:18:29,454 WARN \[restartedMain\] \[\] o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - postProcessAfterInitialization(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:437): Bean 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties' of type \[org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties\] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor \[jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor\]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.

2024-11-14T12:18:29,468 WARN \[restartedMain\] \[\] o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - postProcessAfterInitialization(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:437): Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$PooledDataSourceConfiguration' of type \[org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$PooledDataSourceConfiguration\] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor \[jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor\]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.

2024-11-14T12:18:29,475 WARN \[restartedMain\] \[\] o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - postProcessAfterInitialization(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:437): Bean 'jdbcConnectionDetails' of type \[org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.PropertiesJdbcConnectionDetails\] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor \[jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor\]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.

getting these logs after upgrading to Jdk- 17 and spring boot 3.2.4 and spring batch 5.1.1
could anyone explain this why these warnings coming up ?
